# Replace with sed on csv file

Tags: linux, csv, sed

I have a csv file and I am trying to substitute the last letter for a word...
The input is

1111;AAA;... (more columns);A1a;A

2222;XXX;... (more columns);T3g;B

... (more rows)

...(more rows)

4564;AdA;... (more columns);G1a;A

33321;B1X; ... (more columns);T3g;B

And I want to replace A for "Avocado" and B for "Banana"...

I tried

`#sed -e "s/;A$/;C/g" file.csv`
But doesn't work, any advice, please?

Comment: Sorry, I think you'll need to rephrase this; it's completely unclear from your description what you're trying to achieve.  The `sed` command looks like you're trying to replace every `A` at the end of a line with a `C`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the following what you're trying to achieve?

```
tink@host:~/tmp$ sed 's/A$/Avocado/;s/B$/Banana/' file.csv
1111;AAA;... (more columns);A1a;Avocado
2222;XXX;... (more columns);T3g;Banana
... (more rows)
...(more rows)
4564;AdA;... (more columns);G1a;Avocado
33321;B1X; ... (more columns);T3g;Banana
```

If that looks correct, and you want to change in-file, add a `-i` to sed.
If you want a new file, add a `> new_file` to the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
sed -i 's/A$/Avocado$/g' file.csv
sed -i 's/B$/Banana$/g' file.csv
```

The -i replaces the text and the Regex doesn't need the ; because it should use only one character, right? Therefore, one can just specify that character and replace it with a whole word.